# Does the closure of a smooth algebraic  always define a homology class?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity-theory, differential-topology, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X\subset \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^{N}$ be a smooth, 
algebraic (locally closed)  complex 
submanifold of $\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^N$ 
of complex dimension $k$. More concretely, $X$ is of the 
following type 
$$ X := \{ p \in \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^N: \phi_1(p) =0, \phi_2(p) \neq 0  \} $$
where $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are sections of some holomorphic 
vector bundle and whenever $\phi_2(p) \neq 0$, $\phi_1$ is transverse to the zero set.

Let $\overline{X}$ be the closure of 
$X$ inside $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^N$.

1) 1) Is it true that $\overline{X}$ is an algebraic variety?

2) Is it true that the ``dimension'' of 
$\overline{X}-X$ is strictly less than the dimension of 
$X$?

3) In particular does $\overline{X}$ always define a homology class 
$$ [\overline{X}] \in H_{2k}(\mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^N, \mathbb{Z})  $$
the basic idea being that the singularities of $\overline{X}$ are 
of complex codimension one, hence real codimension two.

Everything is over complex numbers. Note that although $X$ may not 
be connected, I am assuming that every connected component of 
$X$ has the same dimension $k$.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean smooth *algebraic* (locally closed) submanifold? Then the answer to all the questions is yes.

Comment: Thank you for the counter example, in my case I am interested only in algebraic (locally closed) sub manifold. 

Is there a reference for this fact if X is algebaric, ie locally closed?  You are saying in that case the answer is yes.

Comment: $\overline{X}-X$ may not be irreducible: Consider a section $\phi_1\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,O(2))$ defining a smooth conic $C$, and let $\phi_2\in H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,O(1))$ define a line $L$ intersecting $C$ transversely. Then $X$ is $C$ with two points $p,q$ removed, but $\overline{X}-X=${p,q}, which is not an algebraic variety. 

Comment: Actually that was a typo. I meant to ask if $\bar{X}$ is an algebraic 
variety.

Comment: If $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are algebraic, then the answer to all your questions is yes, as Serge Lvovski pointed out above. You can think of $\bar X$ as the variety defined by $\{\Phi_1=0\}$ minus all irreducible components contained in $\{\Phi_2=0\}$. It follows that every irreducible component of $\bar X$ has complex dimension $k$. One way to see that $\bar X$ defines a homology class is to use the existence of a Whitney stratification with all strata being complex varieties.   

Comment: Your title somehow got cut off?

Comment: Regarding Brett Parker's comment: Can you explain why this is true;

``You can think of $\bar{X}$ as the variety defined by 
$\Phi_1 =0 $ minus all irreducible components contained in 
$\Phi_2 =0 $." ?

And I am also not seeing how the next statement follows from this 
fact: 

"It follows that every irreducible component of $\bar{X}$ has complex dimension $k$"


Comment: This is called the "cycle map" from Chow groups to homology groups. One good way to think of (3) (though terrible way to prove it) is to push the fundamental class forward from a resolution $\widetilde X$ of $\overline X$.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand Allen Knutson's comment: You are saying if look up what "cycle map from Chow groups to homology" is I should be able to understand why $\bar{X}$ is the variety $\Phi_1 =0$ minus all irreducible components contained in $\Phi_2 =0$?

Comment: No, I was only commenting on part (3).

Answer (score 2):

1) No. Suppose that $X$ is the set of pairs $(z,w)\in\mathbb C^2$ s.t. $w=e^z$. Then the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is union of $X$ and the line at the infinity (it follows from, say, the big Picard theorem). This is not an algebraic variety.

2) No. In the example above, $\dim(\bar X\setminus X)=\dim X=1$.

Comment: I have edited the question to indicate what $X$ can be. 